# in matplotlib, is there a way to pop up a figure asynchronously?

Tags: matplotlib

In matplotlib, is there a simple way of plotting a figure without interrupting the control flow of the script?

Using pseudocode for clarity, here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
fig1 = figure()
fig1.plot_a_figure(datasets)

for dataset in datasets:
   results = analyze(dataset)    # this takes several minutes
   update(fig1)
   pop_up_another_figure(results) # would like to have a look at this one
                                  # while the next dataset is being processed
```

Of course, I can just savefig() these intermediate figures, but I only need a quick glance at a them and it would be the best to have them just pop up on the screen in real time.

EDIT: A runnable example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pylab as plb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1=plt.figure(1)
ax = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6],'ro-')

#fig1.show()  # this does not show a figure if uncommented
plt.show()    # until the plot window is closed, the next line is not executed

print "doing something else now"
```

Am I missing something very very basic?

Comment: I thought `show()` did that already.  You can create as many figures as you want, show() each of them and they will remain displayed while your code keeps running.  Can you post a runnable example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @ Paul: added an example. Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Nope, you are definitely not missing anything trivial.  I've just seen so many plots pop up simultaneously by accident, I figured there was some threading going on and that show() would not acquire a lock.  Read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659680/matplotlib-simultaneous-plotting-in-multiple-threads/4662511#4662511

Comment: I can think of three ways to go:  first, if you don't care that the plots are interactive, you can, like you suggested, save an image, but then quite easily launch a viewer of that image with `os.startfile()`.  If you want it interactive and you don't mind writing the data to disk, you can `subprocess.Popen()` another python script.  The third would be to try to truly understand how matplotlib manages threads..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First things first, don't forget a simple alternative is to just make new figure windows with `plt.figure(2)`, `plt.figure(3)` etc.  If you really want to update the existing figure window, you had better keep a handle on your lines object with

```
h = ax.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6],'ro-')
```

And then later you would be doing something like:

```
h[0].set_data(some_new_results)
ax.figure.canvas.draw()
```

As for the real meat of the question, if you're still battling with this read on..

---

You need to enable interactive mode if you want `plt.show()` to be non-blocking.  To modify your runnable example so that **"doing something else now"** would print immediately, as opposed to waiting for the figure window to be closed, the following would do:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pylab as plb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1=plt.figure(1)
ax = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6],'ro-')

#fig1.show()  # this does not show a figure if uncommented
plt.ion()     # turns on interactive mode
plt.show()    # now this should be non-blocking

print "doing something else now"
raw_input('Press Enter to continue...')
```

However, this is just scratching the surface of things - there are many complications once you start wanting to do background work while interacting with the plots.  This is a natural consequence of painting with what's essentially a state machine, it doesn't rub well with threading and programming in an object-oriented environment.

- Expensive calculations will have to go into worker threads (or alternatively into subprocesses) to avoid freezing the GUI.
- `Queue` should be used to pass input data and get results out of the worker functions in a thread-safe way.
- In my experience, it is not safe to call `draw()` in the worker thread so you also need to set up a way to schedule a repaint.
- Different backends may start to do strange things and `TkAgg` seems to be the only one which works 100% (see [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/shell.html)).

The easiest and best solution is not to use the vanilla python interpreter, but to use `ipython -pylab` (as ianalis has rightly suggested), because they have already figured out most of the tricks needed to get interactive stuff working smoothly.  It can be done without `ipython`/`pylab` but it's a significant amount of extra work.

*Note:* I still often like to farm off worker threads whilst using ipython and pyplot GUI windows, and to get threading working smoothly I also need to use another commandline argument `ipython -pylab -wthread`.  I'm on `python 2.7.1+` with `matplotlib v1.1.0`, your mileage may vary.  Hope this helps!

*Note for Ubuntu users*: The repositories are still back on v0.99 for quite some time now, it is worth [upgrading](http://git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git) your `matplotlib` because there were [many improvements](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/whats_new.html) coming up to the v1.0 release including a **Bugfix marathon**, and major changes to the behaviour of `show()`.

Comment: tried your example with plt.ion(). Doesn't work for me, plt.show() is still blocking it. I'm on Ubuntu 10.04, python 2.6.5, matplotlib 0.99. Is that just way too old?

Comment: Perhaps it is way too old: they have changed the implementation of `show()` quite significantly back for v1.0 ( see here http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/whats_new.html#multiple-calls-to-show-supported ).  What do you get if you move the `plt.ion()` line up to the top of the script, i.e. after the `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`? And what is the result of calling function `matplotlib.get_backend()`?

Comment: get_backend() returns TkAgg, and there's no change if the the plt.ion() is the first line of the script.

Comment: Is `ax.figure.canvas.draw()` a blocking/synchronous call? I'm unable to find that information anywhere. If you know or have a reference that explains this, would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest solution is to use IPython as your python shell. Run it with the -pylab option.

```
ipython -pylab
```