# How to fix the python multiprocessing matplotlib savefig() issue?

Tags: matplotlib, multiprocessing

I want to speed up matplotlib.savefig() for many figures by multiprocessing module, and trying to benchmark the performance between parallel and sequence.

Below is the codes:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Compare the time of matplotlib savefig() in parallel and sequence
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing
import time


def gen_fig_list(n):
    ''' generate a list to contain n demo scatter figure object '''
    plt.ioff()
    fig_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        plt.figure();
        dt = np.random.randn(5, 4);
        fig = plt.scatter(dt[:,0], dt[:,1], s=abs(dt[:,2]*1000), c=abs(dt[:,3]*100)).get_figure()
        fig.FM_figname = "img"+str(i)
        fig_list.append(fig)
    plt.ion()
    return fig_list


def savefig_worker(fig, img_type, folder):
    file_name = folder+"\\"+fig.FM_figname+"."+img_type
    fig.savefig(file_name, format=img_type, dpi=fig.dpi)
    return file_name


def parallel_savefig(fig_list, folder):
    proclist = []
    for fig in fig_list:
        print fig.FM_figname,
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=savefig_worker, args=(fig, 'png', folder)) # cause error
        proclist.append(p)
        p.start()

    for i in proclist:
        i.join()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder_1, folder_2 = 'Z:\\A1', 'Z:\\A2'
    fig_list = gen_fig_list(10)

    t1 = time.time()
    parallel_savefig(fig_list,folder_1)
    t2 = time.time()
    print '\nMulprocessing time    : %0.3f'%((t2-t1))

    t3 = time.time()
    for fig in fig_list:
        savefig_worker(fig, 'png', folder_2)
    t4 = time.time()
    print 'Non_Mulprocessing time: %0.3f'%((t4-t3))
```

And I meet problem `"This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information."` error caused by `p = multiprocessing.Process(target=savefig_worker, args=(fig, 'png', folder))` .

Why ? And how to solve it ?

(Windows XP + Python: 2.6.1 + Numpy: 1.6.2 + Matplotlib: 1.2.0)

**EDIT: (add error msg on python 2.7.3)**

When run on IDLE of python 2.7.3, it gives below error msg:

```
>>> 
img0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\desktop\mulsavefig_pilot.py", line 61, in <module>
    proc.start()
  File "d:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start

  File "d:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "d:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function notify_axes_change at 0x029F5030>: it's not found as matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4.notify_axes_change
```

**EDIT: (My solution demo)**

inspired by [Matplotlib: simultaneous plotting in multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659680/matplotlib-simultaneous-plotting-in-multiple-threads/4662511#4662511)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Compare the time of matplotlib savefig() in parallel and sequence
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing
import time


def gen_data(fig_qty, bubble_qty):
    ''' generate data for fig drawing '''
    dt = np.random.randn(fig_qty, bubble_qty, 4)
    return dt


def parallel_savefig(draw_data, folder):
    ''' prepare data and pass to worker '''

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    fig_qty = len(draw_data)
    fig_para = zip(range(fig_qty), draw_data, [folder]*fig_qty)

    pool.map(fig_draw_save_worker, fig_para)
    return None


def fig_draw_save_worker(args):
    seq, dt, folder = args
    plt.figure()
    fig = plt.scatter(dt[:,0], dt[:,1], s=abs(dt[:,2]*1000), c=abs(dt[:,3]*100), alpha=0.7).get_figure()
    plt.title('Plot of a scatter of %i' % seq)
    fig.savefig(folder+"\\"+'fig_%02i.png' % seq)
    plt.close()
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder_1, folder_2 = 'A1', 'A2'
    fig_qty, bubble_qty =  500, 100
    draw_data = gen_data(fig_qty, bubble_qty)

    print 'Mulprocessing  ...   ',
    t1 = time.time()
    parallel_savefig(draw_data, folder_1)
    t2 = time.time()
    print 'Time : %0.3f'%((t2-t1))

    print 'Non_Mulprocessing .. ', 
    t3 = time.time()
    for para in zip(range(fig_qty), draw_data, [folder_2]*fig_qty):
        fig_draw_save_worker(para)
    t4 = time.time()
    print 'Time : %0.3f'%((t4-t3))

    print 'Speed Up: %0.1fx'%(((t4-t3)/(t2-t1)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not really a bug, per-say, more of a limitation.

The explanation is in the last line of your error mesage:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function notify_axes_change at 0x029F5030>: it's not found as matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4.notify_axes_change
```

It is telling you that elements of the figure objects can not be pickled, which is how `MultiProcess` passes data between the processes.  The objects are pickled in the main processes, shipped as pickles, and then re-constructed on the other side.  Even if you fixed *this* exact issue (maybe by using a different backend, or stripping off the offending function (which might break things in other ways)) I am pretty sure there are core parts of `Figure`, `Axes`, or `Canvas` objects that can not be pickled.

As @bigbug point to, an example of how to get around this limitation, [Matplotlib: simultaneous plotting in multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659680/matplotlib-simultaneous-plotting-in-multiple-threads/4662511#4662511).  The basic idea is that you push your *entire* plotting routine off to the sub-process so you only push `numpy` arrays an maybe some configuration information across the process boundry.

Comment: so does it mean i have to give up the idea to savefig() by multiprocessing ? or any other idea to speed up the savefig?

Comment: It means you have to do it differently, you need to push the _entire_ plotting step off to the sub-process.  That is push pure data across the process boundary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659680/matplotlib-simultaneous-plotting-in-multiple-threads/4662511#4662511

Answer (score 9):

You can try to move all of the matplotlib code(including the import) to a function.

1. Make sure you don't have a import matplotlib or import matplotlib.pyplot as plt at the top of your code.
2. create a function that does all the matplotlib including the import.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import pool

def graphing_function(graph_data):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.figure()
    plt.hist(graph_data.data)
    plt.savefig(graph_data.filename)
    plt.close()
    return

pool = Pool(4)
pool.map(graphing_function, data_list)
```

Comment: why does this work?!? On a windows or Linux machine running python3.5.2, matplotlib 2.1, numpy 1.13 I can have keep the import matplotlib globally and everything works. On OS-X when I run the code I get complaints about "__THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__". Putting the imports inside the called function make it work normally.

Comment: @rocketman because MacOSX runs threads and your multiprocessing uses fork(). It is **impossible** to safely fork from a multithreaded program and continue. And that is the case with MacOSX. The solution is to make multiprocessing to use spawnserver