# Dask delayed + Matplotlib.savefig() -> FAIL

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing, dask, dask-delayed

My goal is to produce multiple png files from respectively multiple numpy arrays, loaded from medical images in my HD.
To make things quicker, I'm using dask delayed.
Here's my working code:

```
import os.path
from glob import glob

import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
from dask import delayed

def process(data):
    # Need to have the import inside so that multiprocessing works.
    # Apparently doesn't solve the issue anyway..
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    outpath = '/Users/user/outputdir/'
    name = os.path.basename(data.get_filename())
    savename = name[:name.index('.')] + '.png'

    plt.imshow(np.rot90(data.get_data()[15:74, 6:82, 18, 0]),
               extent=[0, 1, 0, 1], aspect=1.28, cmap='gray')
    plt.axis('off')
    out = os.path.join(outpath, savename)
    plt.savefig(out)
    plt.close()
    return out


L = []
for fn in glob("/Users/user/imagefiles/mb*.nii.gz"):
    nifti = delayed(nib.load)(fn)
    outpng = delayed(process)(nifti)
    L.append(outpng)

results = delayed(print)(L)
results.compute()
```

My problem is that after each run some of the output images are empty (nothing in the png), and which images are empty seem pretty random, since all input data is valid.

I suspect this is a problem of multiprocessing and matplotlib, as seen in [other related thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525431/how-to-fix-the-python-multiprocessing-matplotlib-savefig-issue)

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get this working with `dask`?

**EDIT: Minimal working example**

```
import os.path
import random
import string

import numpy as np
from dask import delayed

def gendata(fn):
    return

def process(data):
    # Need to have the import inside so that multiprocessing works.
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    outpath = '/Users/user/Pictures/test/'
    name = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=10))
    savename = name + '.png'

    data = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(100,100,20,2))

    plt.imshow(np.rot90(data[15:74, 6:82, 18, 0]),
               extent=[0, 1, 0, 1], aspect=1.28, cmap='gray')
    plt.axis('off')
    out = os.path.join(outpath, savename)
    plt.savefig(out)
    plt.close()
    return out

L = []
for fn in range(0, 10):
    nifti = delayed(gendata)(fn)
    outpng = delayed(process)(nifti)
    L.append(outpng)

results = delayed(print)(L)
results.compute()
```

Comment: Is this specific to the data in use or would you be able to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sorry for that. Just added one. The code also works perfectly fine if I remove the calls to "delayed" and just run everything sequentially.

Comment: Would suggest raising this to the Dask [issue tracker]( https://github.com/dask/dask/issues ) with a link back to this post. Also would suggest adding the `dask` and `dask-delayed` labels above.