# Python multiprocessing+savefig leads to error or system lockup

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, figure, python-multiprocessing

I have a big 3d numpy array, each slice (2d array) of I want to write out to an imshow-like figure (i.e. a heatmap of the values). As a concrete example, say the array is of shape 3x3x3000, so I want 3000 images, each of which represents a 3x3 matrix. Looping over it with a single thread is a bit slow. Since the iterations are completely independent, I thought to use the multiprocessing module to speed it up a bit. Code is as below.

```
def write_tensor_image(t_slice_wrapper):

    idx = t_slice_wrapper['idx']
    t_slice = t_slice_wrapper['t_slice']
    folder_path=t_slice_wrapper['folder_path']

    fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    
    ax.imshow(t_slice,interpolation='none')
    fig.tight_layout()

    fname_ = os.path.join(folder_path,'tmp_%s.png'%str(idx))
    fig.savefig(fname_, bbox_inches="tight")    

def write_tensor_image_sequence(tensor, folder_path='/home/foo/numpy_cache'):

    os.system('mkdir -p %s'%folder_path)
    os.system('rm -rf %s/*'%folder_path)

    slices = [None]*tensor.shape[2]
    for i in range(0,tensor.shape[2]):
        slices[i] = {'t_slice':tensor[:,:,i], 'idx':i, 'folder_path':folder_path}

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(write_tensor_image, slices)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

However this does not work - the single threaded case works fine (just calling write_tensor_image() in the for-loop) but using the pool either causes total lockup of the machine or gives something like the following error:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
  after 849 requests (849 known processed) with 28 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
  after 849 requests (849 known processed) with 28 events remaining.
  after 849 requests (849 known processed) with 28 events remaining.
X Error of failed request:  BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  54 (X_FreePixmap)
Resource id in failed request:  0x4e0001e
Serial number of failed request:  851
Current serial number in output stream:  851
```

I think I'm on the right track (according to e.g. [How to fix the python multiprocessing matplotlib savefig() issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525431/how-to-fix-the-python-multiprocessing-matplotlib-savefig-issue) and [Matplotlib: simultaneous plotting in multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659680/matplotlib-simultaneous-plotting-in-multiple-threads/4662511#4662511)), but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `matplotlib.use('agg')` at the head of the script. Matplotlib appears to be trying to establish a GUI in each sub-process, which are conflicting with one-another.

More generally, you may not want to use the pyplot interface, but rather the OOP one, in cases where you are not doing standard interactive plotting.

Comment: Hmm, just tried this (also capitalized as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931376/generating-matplotlib-graphs-without-a-running-x-server), but still generates the error. Also tried matplotlib.pyplot.ioff(). No difference :(

Searching for OOP (object oriented?) interface to matplotlib didn't turn up much.

This is my first 48 hours of numerical development in python (previously Matlab), so I don't really know the nuances yet.

Comment: Solved: I had imported pyplot in another module, which I turn imported before setting the matplotlib backend.  So matplotlib was saying that the matplotlib.use() call had no effect. Works now. Thanks!